# How to define event with controller method in laravel web.php file?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have define controller method call in web.php as below.

```
Route::post('/order', 'OrderController@create');
```

I want to call event when OrderController@create method called. How can i do that? My event call is

```
event(new NewOrderAdded());
```

Here is my event class.

```
class NewOrderAdded implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('public-test-channel');
    }
}
```

Controller class

```
class OrderController extends Controller
{
  public function create(Request $request){
    $order = new Order([
      'user_id' => $request->get('user_id'),
      'person_id' => json_encode($request->get('person_id')),
      'date_of_booking' => $request->get('date_of_booking'),
      'total_order_price' =>$request->get('total_order_price'),
      'ticket_id' => json_encode($request->get('ticket_id')),
      'timeslot' => $request->get('timeslot'),
      'status' => 'pending',
      'add_on_id' => json_encode($request->get('add_on_id'))
    ]);
    $order->save();
    event(new NewOrderAdded($order));
    return response()->json(array('order_id'=>$order->id));
  }
}
```

Here is the clas where i want to receive event.
ViewBookings.vue

```
<script>
import moment from 'moment';
export default{
  data(){
    return{
      users:[]
    }
  },
  created:function(){
    this.listen();
  },
  methods:{
    listen(){
      Echo.channel('public-test-channel')
            .listen('NewOrderAdded', (data) => {
              console.log("Event received");
            });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried this code but i am not able to receive events in ViewBookings.vue class. Please suggest what is the issue here.

Comment: just call it from your controller

Comment: @usrNotFound, but how?

Comment: Check this, how to dispatch event in controller : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events#dispatching-events

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:
please check in your application `namespace App\Providers;` this path for event to listener mapping.

Step 2:
Add this line in your function:

```
Event::fire(app()->make('App\Events\YourEventClassName', [$data]));
```

$data is optional.

Step 3:
Write all the code you want to do in listener, which you have already mapped.

Answer (score 1):

Alright you can use observers if you want or call event straight from controller.

Here is how you use observer

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;


use App\Order;


class OrderObserver
{
/**
 * Listen to the Order created event.
 *
 * @param  Order  $order
 * @return void
 */
public function created(Order $order)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Listen to the Order deleting event.
 *
 * @param  Order  $order
 * @return void
 */
public function deleting(Order $order)
{
    //
}
}
```

in your AppServiceProvider include `Order::observe(OrderObserver::class);` in `boot` method

Now every time you create or delete `Order` object created or deleting will triggered.

Or if you want to use controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\controller;


class OrderController extends Controller
{

  public function store(Request $request)
  {
     //.......
     //after saving call your
    event(new NewOrderAdded()) //even better pass user object here
  }

}
```